# Foundry Sync Backing Dataset

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

How can we find the backing dataset for a table which is being queried by using Foundry Postgres SQL service in slate?

Edit: We do have a way to find sync information from Details Tab in a dataset. I want to reverse enginner this. To find a way to get dataset details using foundry sync table name as i don't know the main dataset.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do?

Comment: In my environment (I do not know how much it's customized vs Palantir's standard), you need to know the main dataset, then go to sync detail in the 'Detail' tab

Comment: @fmsf: I have a slate application where we query foundry sync tables. But I have no means to find the synced dataset as table name and sync name are different.

Comment: @Christophe: I want to reverse engineer this. Get dataset details using foundry sync table as I don't know the main dataset.

Comment: OK, I get your point and the question is interesting. I suggest you update your initial post to explain this, I will look forward finding some idées accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata related to the mapping from a dataset RID to a postgres table is stored in the `postgate.dataset` table, however only the administrator account has permissions to query the `postgate` schema. If you've "lost" the source dataset and can't find it by looking at the possible input datasets in the Dataset preview, you can reach out to your Foundry Support contact to get further help.

The general best practice is to manually add the relevant datasets into the **Dataset** tab in the Slate app - I normally do this even if I'm primarily using the **Platform** tab to read from the object layer instead of from Postgres.

The reason this isn't automatically inferred is because Slate doesn't actually introspect your query and you can write queries that dynamically choose which table to query at runtime.